# using AWK to edit a text file and make a new text file

Tags: awk

I have a comma separated text file with 5 columns which looks like this:

```
##Count,Frequency,Distance,Sequence,Translation
122712,0.0212055,20-30,GCATGTTTCGTTATGTCTGAAGGTTACGACGAATTCTGTGGCCCG,ACFVMSEGYDEFCGP
76501,0.0132199,20-30,GCATGTCCGCATGAATTCTTCGTTGAAGCTTACCCGTGTGGCCCG,ACPHEFFVEAYPCGP
60485,0.0104522,20-33,GCATGTCTGTCTCTGTTCGCTGAAGGTGAACTGCTGGACTGTGGCCCG,ACFVMSEGYDEFCGP
59365,0.0102587,20-30,GCATGTATCTCTATGGCTGAAGGTGACGACGACTGGTGTGGCCCG,ACISMAEGDDDWCGP
```

I am trying to make a new file only with unique values of column 5 (if the value in the 5th column is repeated in other rows I will use the first row and filter out the rest).
expected output will look like this:

```
##Count,Frequency,Distance,Sequence,Translation
122712,0.0212055,20-30,GCATGTTTCGTTATGTCTGAAGGTTACGACGAATTCTGTGGCCCG,ACFVMSEGYDEFCGP
76501,0.0132199,20-30,GCATGTCCGCATGAATTCTTCGTTGAAGCTTACCCGTGTGGCCCG,ACPHEFFVEAYPCGP
59365,0.0102587,20-30,GCATGTATCTCTATGGCTGAAGGTGACGACGACTGGTGTGGCCCG,ACISMAEGDDDWCGP
```

to do so I wrote the following code in `AWK`

```
awk '!h[$5]++ { NF--; print }' FS=, OFS=, infile.csv > outfile.csv
```

but it does not return my expected output. do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Maybe you just wanted `awk '!h[$5]++' FS=, OFS=, infile.csv > outfile.csv`?

Comment: What are you hoping the `NF--` should do anyway?

Comment: Why are you decreasing `NF` i.e. number of fields?

Comment: Your examples are hard to follow because it's visually difficult to tell apart the "sequence" field. Could you simplify and give examples of desired result (including duplicates)

Comment: decreasing `NF` is undefined behavior. In some awks it'll remove the last field(s), in other awks it'll do nothing, and in yet other awks it could do anything else (e.g. wipe your hard drive) and still be POSIX compliant.

Comment: @user... you said `it does not return my expected output.` - it'll be easier for us to help solve your problem if you [edit] your question to show us, and tell us what the problem is with, the erroneous output you got.

Answer (score 0):

OP's code can be simplified to:

```
awk -F',' '!h[$5]++' infile.csv
```

This generates:

```
122712,0.0212055,20-30,GCATGTTTCGTTATGTCTGAAGGTTACGACGAATTCTGTGGCCCG,ACFVMSEGYDEFCGP
76501,0.0132199,20-30,GCATGTCCGCATGAATTCTTCGTTGAAGCTTACCCGTGTGGCCCG,ACPHEFFVEAYPCGP
59365,0.0102587,20-30,GCATGTATCTCTATGGCTGAAGGTGACGACGACTGGTGTGGCCCG,ACISMAEGDDDWCGP
```

Comment: If you rename `h[]` to `seen[]` it'll be **the** common, idiomatic awk solution.